# Verifying user is still valid with passport and Google

Tags: express, oauth-2.0

When using OAuth2 against Google (or actually any external provider), how is it possible to verify that the user is still logged in to their Google account on the browser and their user is in good standing?
I don't want disabled users to access the system after they have been disabled, and to make sure that the web app cannot be accessed by anyone using my browser after I logged out of Google without having to delete a bunch of cookies for each site.
Is this even possible?
I explored querying the user ID with the users API but it requires authentication to make the query, and the anonymous API does not work for users without a Google+ account (or at least, not that I could find).
In addition, the users API will not help if the user logged off.
I'm using node.js with express.js and passport.js for authentication, with a cookie session.

Comment: the spec of oAuth does not support that. maybe google does, but you say "or any other external provider", so you mean something generic. So oAuth specification does not support that....